# How can I use the Bing Maps API to check if a postcode exists?

Tags: bing-maps

I need to use the Bing Maps API to check if a UK postcode (Not sure how different it is for other countries) is valid.

It seems that I can put any nonsense into the field for postcode and I still get a response.

E.G.  http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/GB/aregsfdgsdfgsdfgdsf?key=BINGMAPSKEYHERE

Gives a result that has a lat and long of 53.9438323974609, -2.55055809020996 in the "point" field, despite that clearly not being a valid postcode.

Is there a way that I can simply test the validity of a postcode?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the response object for your request you will see a matchCode value. This indicates if the match it is good or not. In this case it says "UpHierarchy" which indicates that it didn't find the exact result so it when up the address hierarchy until it found a result. The result being returned is for the United Kingdom. Additionally, the results also have an entityType value which tells you the type location that was found. In this case it says CountryRegion. You want an entityType value of "PostalCode". By checking these two values you can determine if the returned result is a postal code or not. More details on the geocode response object is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701725.aspx

One thing I would highlight is that the URL format you are using is a bit of a legacy one and isn't as accurate as passing in a single string query (i.e. &q=YOURQUERY). This is highlighted in the [best practices docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894107.aspx). If you are using .NET, I hiehgly recommend using the [Bing Maps .NET REST toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit). It makes things really easy and implements best practices for you.